# Let $X \sim N(4,3)$ and $Y \sim N(2,4)$. Which of the following do we know for sure about $X+Y$?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

That

- $Var(X+Y)=7$
- $E(X+Y)=6$
- $X+Y$ is normally distributed.
- $X+Y$ is not normally distributed.

*My answer*

It follows from the linearitet of $E$ that $E(X+Y) = 6$. I do not know how to determine whether the rest is true or not.

Answer (score 0):

You conclusion about the expected value, and your reason for your conlusion are correct.

Now consider:
$$\operatorname{var}(X+Y) = \operatorname{var}(X) + \operatorname{var}(Y) + 2\operatorname{cov}(X,Y).$$
Now suppose
\begin{align}
X & = Z_1 + Z_2 + Z_3 + 4 \\
Y & = Z_2 + Z_3 + Z_4 + Z_5 + 2 \\
\text{where } & Z_1,Z_2,Z_3,Z_4 \sim \text{i.i.d.} \operatorname N(0,1).
\end{align}
Then the distributions of $X$ and $Y$ are just those that you specified, but $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)\ne 0.$

There are also cases where $X+Y$ is not normally distributed. For example, suppose $X\sim\operatorname N(4,3)$ and
$$
Y = 2 + 2\times\begin{cases} (X-4)/\sqrt 3 & \text{if “heads''} \\ (4-X)/\sqrt 3 & \text{if “tails''} \end{cases}
$$
where $\text{“heads''}$ or $\text{“tails''}$ is the outcome of the toss of a fair coin that is indpendent of $X$.

In that case, $X$ and $Y$ have the specified distributions, but it is not hard to show that $X+Y$ is not normally distributed. Thus the pair $(X,Y)$ does not have a bivariate normal distribution.

Comment: Could you make your answer without cov. We do not learn about this in the course. Thank you.

Comment: @Xenusi : ok, Just take the definitions of $X$ and $Y$ that I specified in this answer and compute the variance of $X+Y= Z_1 + 2Z_2 + 2Z_3 + Z_4 + Z_5. \qquad$

Comment: How can you decompose each in the way you did? How you used a theorem?

Comment: @Xenusi : I didn't decompose them; I constructed them. I said suppose $Z_i \sim\operatorname N(0,1)$ for $i=1,\ldots,5$ and these are mutually independent, and then let $X$ and $Y$ be certain functions of those.